# EM Daemon is not running oracle database 11g R2

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

the Oracle database GUI application is not working 
i have tried this but I always get this error.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>emctl status dbconsole
Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.2.0
Copyright (c) 1996, 2010 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
https://localhost:1158/em/console/aboutApplication
EM Daemon is not running.
------------------------------------------------------------------
Logs are generated in directory 
C:\app\AbdeAMNR\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/localhost_orcl/sysman/log
```

Comment: This might seem obvious, but... why not start the daemon, with `emctl start dbconsole` ?

Comment: this is exactly what I have done, but why it does not work

Comment: Then you need to look at the logs to see why.